# Init for a SwiftUI class with a @Binding var

Tags: class, binding, swiftui, init

I have a class which I want to initialize with a Binding var that is set in another View.

The View:

```swift
struct CoverPageView: View {
    @State var numberOfNumbers: Int

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0){
                    TextField("Multiplication Up to:", value: self.$numberOfNumbers, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The class which needs to be initialized using the @Binding var $numberOfNumbers:

```swift
import SwiftUI

class MultiplicationPractice: ObservableObject {
    @Binding var numberOfNumbers: Int
    var classNumOfNumbers: Int

    init() {
        self.classNumOfNumbers = self.$numberOfNumbers
    }
}
```

The init statement obviously gives the error that self is not initialized and the instance var is being used to initialize, which is not allowed.

How do I circumvent this? The class needs to be initialized with the number the user enters in the first view. I have written approx. code here so ignore any typos please.

Comment: You don't pass it with `var classNumofNumbers:Int`, pass it directly from the init function. `MultiplicationPractice(numberOfNumbers: $numberOfNumbers)`

Comment: Sorry - I have showed it like this because the actual class has a published var of the same class.  As soon as I pass the $numOfNumbers to the initializer - it gives self is not initialized error - which is the same if you want to initialize a var with the binding value. --

Comment: --something like - import SwiftUI

class MultiplicationPractice:ObservableObject {
    
    Binding var numberOfNumbers:Int
    Published var MulGame:MultiplicationGame = MultiplicationGame(maxNumber: $numberofNumbers)} // - this is where it gives the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you'd initialize MultiplicationPractice in CoverPageView with a starting value:

```
@ObservedObject var someVar = MultiplicationPractice(NoN:123)
```

And of course, add a supporting init statement:

```
class MultiplicationPractice:ObservableObject {
    init(NoN: Int) {
        self.numberOfNumbers = val
    }
```

and you wouldn't want to wrap your var with @Binding, instead wrap it with @Published:

```
class MultiplicationPractice:ObservableObject {

@Published var numberOfNumbers:Int
...
```

In your particular case I would even drop the `numberOfNumbers` var in your `CoverPageView`, and instead use the direct variable of the above `someVar`:

```
struct CoverPageView: View {
    //removed @State  var numberOfNumbers:Int
    @ObservedObject var someVar = MultiplicationPractice(123)
    
    ...
    
    TextField("Multiplication Upto:", value: self.$someVar.numberOfNumbers, formatter: NumberFormatter())
```

You'll notice that I passed in the sub-var of the @ObservedObject as a binding. We can do this with ObservableObjects.

---

### Edit

I see now what you're trying to do, you want to pass a binding along across your ViewModel, and establish an indirect connection between your view and model. While this may not be the way I'd personally do it, I can still provide a working example.

Here is a simple example using your struct names:

```
struct MultiplicationGame {
    @Binding var maxNumber:String
    init(maxNumber: Binding<String>) {
        self._maxNumber = maxNumber
        print(self.maxNumber)
    }
}

class MultiplicationPractice:ObservableObject {
    var numberOfNumbers: Binding<String>
    @Published var MulGame:MultiplicationGame
    
    init(numberOfNumbers: Binding<String> ) {
        self.numberOfNumbers = numberOfNumbers
        self.MulGame = MultiplicationGame(maxNumber: numberOfNumbers)
    }
    
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var someText: String
    @ObservedObject var mulPractice: MultiplicationPractice
    init() {
        let state = State(initialValue: "")
        self._someText = state
        self.mulPractice = MultiplicationPractice(numberOfNumbers: state.projectedValue)
    }
    var body: some View {
        TextField("put your text here", text: $someText)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out and replying - Sorry for the confusing code. - the coverpageview is the master (the truth) - this is where the user inputs the numberOfNumbers.   Class MultiplicationPractice is my viewmodel which needs this numberofNumbers in order to access my model (another struct) with no view body).                                                                                                         so Multiplication practice is the one where the data should flow to not the other way round.

Comment: This is the class -                                                                                                       import SwiftUI class MultiplicationPractice:ObservableObject { Binding var numberOfNumbers:Int Published var MulGame:MultiplicationGame = MultiplicationGame(maxNumber: $numberofNumbers)} // - this is where it gives the error –

Comment: I see. So your effectively trying to hand off numberOfNumbers from the view, to the viewmodel, and then finally from the viewmodel to the model. I'll update my answer.

Comment: This is great -thanks. The code compiles and works. I still seem to be having an issue where I cannot go beyond the init value. e.g if I put the initial value of the state as 10 - then if the user inputs 11 - then all my array indexes start going out of bounds whereas if the user inputs 9 - then there is no issue and the view is generated fine!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don't really understand your question so I'm just going to list a few examples and hopefully one of them will be what you're looking for.

---

```swift
struct SuperView: some View {
    @State var value: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        SubView(value: self.$value)
    }
}
struct SubView: View {
    @Binding var value: Int

    // This is the same as the compiler-generated memberwise initializer
    init(value: Binding<Int>) {
        self._value = value
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(value)")
    }
}
```

---

If I misunderstood and you're just trying to get the current value, do this

```swift
struct SuperView: some View {
    @State var value: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        SubView(value: self.value)
    }
}
struct SubView: View {
    let value: Int

    // This is the same as the compiler-generated memberwise initializer
    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(value)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - Sorry for the confusing code. - the coverpageview is the master (the truth) - this is where the user inputs the numberOfNumbers. Class MultiplicationPractice is my viewmodel which needs this numberofNumbers in order to access my model (another struct) with no view body). so Multiplication practice is the one where the data should flow to not the other way round.

Comment: Your example snippet is using two views - but I have a view and a class - I have one view which gets the value from the user - and then this value needs to be passed to a class. (and issue is mainly also because being a class it needs to have all vars initialized)

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't really understand — maybe you'll be able to use the same ideas that I put in my example, or @Samuel-IH's answer might help you